# Bootstrap 4 - full page, two columns + visible footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to do a simple "login" page. I discovered this template here: https://www.codeply.com/go/GeBvYXxFKY

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center h-100 bg-dark text-white" id="header">
    <h1 class="display-4">Hello.</h1>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row h-100 mt-5">
        <main class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Content...</h1>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This looks great and I can easily adjust accordingly. But I really like the layout where the "Hello." would appear center (aligned in the middle vertically and horizontally) and on the left-hand side taking up 9/12 of the column space and the form, the remain 3/12 of the column space.

But every time I try to separate the columns so I can do that I lose the full screen.

The next issue is where the "Content..." is displayed. I'd like to replace that with a permanent footer that appears to take up approximately 15% of the page (give or take, I haven't worked that out yet, but I can play).

I have a rough idea of how I want it to look (here's an MS Paint realisation of my dream):
[image: Picture showing display]

My thoughts are that this won't be scrollable that this would be the entire page.

Thanks for looking at this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's your `h-100`class on `#content` maybe messing around with your real page.

From that bit of code , you could do :

```css
/* here missing or extra class */

.screen {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* or height or h-100 if already used with html & body */
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-grow-4 {
  flex-grow: 4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="screen d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center flex-grow-4 bg-dark text-white" id="header">
    <h1 class="display-4 col-sm-4 col-md-9 text-center">Hello.</h1>
    <form class="col-md-3 col-sm-6  p-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container flex-grow-1" id="content">
    <div class="row  mt-5">
      <main class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Content...</h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And  also drop the col-xx-xx clas and set a max/min width to the form.

```css
/* here missing or extra class */

.screen {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* or height or h-100 if already used with html & body */
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-grow-4 {
  flex-grow: 4;
}

.minW-10em {
  min-width: 10em;
}

.maxW-25em {
  max-width: 25em;
}

/* end extra login page */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="screen d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center flex-grow-4 bg-dark text-white" id="header">
    <h1 class="display-4 col flex-grow-1 text-center">Hello.</h1>
    <form class=" p-5 minW-10em maxW-25em ">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="container flex-grow-1" id="content">
    <div class="row  mt-5">
      <main class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Content...</h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow... I think this works. I'm just reading through this, I'll put it in piece by piece to see that this is the desired outcome (the snippet works as wanted) and I'll come back and give you the tick.

Comment: The only problem when I try this on a large screen, the footer takes up about 2/3 of the screen and the login details are small. I'm just playing around with it to see why that is.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was it - I hadn't updated the CSS file. Appreciate it. This is the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: This was great, thank you. I took quite the springboard from here and was able to capitalise on your great work. Thank you. I have modified everything to fit exactly as needed. I did have to add a few rows and containers here and there, but you're idea there was definitely the springboard I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
<h1 class="display-4 col-6">Hello.</h1>
<form class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" 
         type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" 
        type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good except it does not occupy the whole screen and doesn't seem to center vertically. I'm going to play with this a little.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-row justify-content-center h-100 bg-dark text-white" id="header">
    <div class="col-9 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row h-100 mt-5">
        <main class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Content...</h1>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you to read [How to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve the possibilities to help the user who ask.